# View Hidden Folders in Browsers "Browse"

Tags: html

Is it possible to view hidden folders in a browsers "browse" input?

`<input type = 'file' name = 'file' />`

For example, can you navigate to the Roaming folder on Windows?

Comment: That's not something you can control via a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.

That is a function that each browser will handle natively you have no control over how it works.

Perhaps, you could implement an [HTML5 style drag and drop,](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/) which means the user could drag a file from anywhere they like.